# Changing data types in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have several tables in SQL Server 2005 that have columns with datatype `money`. I would like to change them into datatype `numeric(20, 2)`. I am a lazy guy so would like to update each and every money data types to numeric data types with as little hassle as possible.

Can anyone help please.

Thank you so very much.

Comment: Main question is: **WHY???** What's bugging you about the `money` datatype, or what do you expect to get more / better from a `numeric(20, 2)` type??

Answer (score 0):

alter table yourtable alter column yourcolumn numeric(20, 2) null

Answer (score 0):

Remeber to use the smallest datatype that is possible. A numeric(20,2) will take 13 bytes for every column and every row and the performance will suffer. If you can use numeric(19,2) you will only use 9 bytes instead. With monye you will use 8 bytes and you can handle values up to 922 337 203 685 477.5807